# Issues with a search bar

Tags: php, mysql, searchbar

I really need some help with this one.
I'm trying to create a search bar for my site that will display the proteins that are available. I'v not got much knowledge on how to do this and im using some script that I have been given form my tutor.

This is the script so far

```
<?php

 $search = $_GET["search"];

  require "db.inc";


$connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);


  mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection);

  $query = "SELECT  protien.ProtienID,  
                 protien.Protien Image,
                 protien.Protien Name,
                 protien.Protien Flavour,
                 protien.Protien Price,
         protien.Protien Description
        FROM     protien";


if ($search != "All")

//   $query .= " AND r.region_name = 'Coonawarra' ";
  $query .= " AND Protien Name = '$regionName' ";



 $query .= " ORDER BY Protien Name";


 $result = mysql_query($query,$connection) OR die(mysql_error($query));

 ?>
```

And the form is

```
div class="SideBar">
<div id="tfheader">
        <form  method="get" action="ProteinSearch.php"  id="searchform"> 
  <input  type="text" name="search" /> 
      <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" /> 
    </form>
```

Comment: backtick all the fields names `Protien Name` since there are spaces and mysql will return error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this like

```
if ($search != "All")
   $query .= " WHERE `Protien Name` = '$regionName' ";
```

You have to use `WHERE` instead of `AND` and also your column name contains space so you need to enclose it with `backquotes`.

Comment: Thanks sorted it now!